# Как удалить из схемы только пустые таблицы с названием, начинающимся на tmp_123...?

Tags: postgresql

Добрый вечер!

В цикле с помощью pg_class создала временные таблички, в которые сохранила данные до обновления на случай, если потребуется откат.
В нескольких таблицах пусто, так как не было связанных данных. И теперь нужно оставить только таблички, содержащие информацию. 
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как удалить из схемы только пустые таблицы с названием, начинающимся на tmp_123... ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - создать функцию, которая:

1. Выбирает все имена подходящих таблиц;
2. Проверяет сколько в таблице записей;
3. Удаляет пустые.

Например:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_tmp_123()
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    check_table varchar;
    count_rows integer;
    removed_tables integer;
BEGIN
    removed_tables := 0;
    FOR check_table IN
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        where 1=1
            and table_catalog = 'you_db_name'
            and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
            and table_name ilike 'tmp_123%'
    LOOP
        execute format('SELECT COUNT(*) from  %I ;', check_table) into count_rows;
        IF (count_rows = 0)
        then
            execute format('DROP TABLE  %I ;', check_table);
            removed_tables := removed_tables + 1;
        end IF;
    END LOOP;

RETURN removed_tables;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Проверка:

```
# create  table tmp_123 (name varchar);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 99,390 ms

# create  table tmp_123534 (name varchar);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 120,950 ms

# create  table tmp_12325t343 (name varchar);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 62,786 ms

# insert into tmp_123534(name) values ('1234546');
INSERT 0 1
Time: 21,371 ms

=# select remove_tmp_123();
 remove_tmp_123 
----------------
              2
(1 row)

# SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
where 1=1
    and table_catalog = 'you_db_name'
    and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    and table_name ilike 'tmp_123%'
;

 table_name 
------------
 tmp_123534
(1 row)
```